# Access classes from one project in another Java Web project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to use a class from some project in another Java Web project. Unfortunately I don`t know what I have do to call this class. I understand I have to write package etc. but how?

This class is visible in Java website project

```
public class MojaWygenerowanaKlasaa {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Test2 test2 = new Test2();
String Zmienna = test2.query2();
    }
    // public string Query2() {
      //      return jpsquerie1.dana;
        //}

}
```

This class is visible in another project SBQL4J_EXAMPLE1 -> file(src) -> package -> example

```
package example;

public class Test2 {
    public String query1(){

        return "aa";
    }
}
```

I added the project [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe9hH.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see you have already added the project that contains classes you need to another project's *build path* ("Required projects on the build path" on the picture above).

Now in the file that needs that class just **import that class**.

Example:

```
import pl.example.SomeClass;

public class Test {
  ...

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
    ...
  }
  ...

}
```

In other words, you can freely acces all classes that are on the **project's build path** in a standard way.